# Calling a Constructor method in a GUI

Tags: java, swing

I am currently working on an assignment and I am looking for some help. I was given a class called ProductButton and instructed to finish the constructor method. The javadoc are as follows:

```
/**
Creates a button that will display an image of the product
(assumed to be stored in a file starting with the specified
name and ending with ".jpg"), the specified product name,
and the specified price (formatted properly); the text is 
displayed below the image and is centered.
@param name The product name.
@param price The selling price for this product.
*/
```

In addition, I am to create a driver program. I have the majority of the driver finished, as I am not looking for help with the formatting, layout, or responses to the actions, but how I would create the constructor and call it in my GUI driver to be properly created. I am a first time java user and this is, in a way, foreign to me. Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

Here is what I have tried so far;

```
    public ProductButton (String name, double price) {
    productName = name;
    productPrice = price;

    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    ImageIcon Icon = new ImageIcon(getName() + ".JPG");
    JButton Button = new JButton(getName() + "" + formatter.format(getPrice()), Icon);
    Button.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
    Button.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
```

Comment: The constructor method is simply the initialization function for that object. It sounds like you want a custom button which extends `JButton`, and in order for this button to work, you must have an initialization function. The constructor takes two arguments: A `String name` and a `double price`. So if your custom button is of type `MyButton`, you need a constructor method with this header: `MyButton(String name, double price)`. You "call" a constructor like so: `MyButton b = new MyButton(name, price);`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help others answer your question better, please include some sample code that shows us what you have already tried, and why it doesn't work, or what's missing. Also, you should limit your posts to one question per post.

Comment: Does the class `ProductButton` extend `JButton`?

Comment: Yes it does. I was able to figure it all out! Although, I am now having trouble getting the source of the action to trigger a response. I have, for example 
    ProductButton adultTicket = new ProductButton("Adult Ticket", 12.50);
  adultTicket.addActionListener(this);

as my object, and then I call on the source in my 
    actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 

using 

    if (e.getSource() == adultTicket) { //rest of instructions }

Yet it is not acing as if it is an actual button.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors have one purpose in life: to create an instance of a class.

Constructors and methods differ in three aspects of the signature: modifiers, return type, and name. Like methods, constructors can have any of the access modifiers: public, protected, private, or none (often called package or friendly). Unlike methods, constructors can take only access modifiers. Therefore, constructors cannot be abstract, final, native, static, or synchronised.

Constructors and methods use the keyword this quite differently. A method uses this to refer to the instance of the class that is executing the method. Static methods do not use this; they do not belong to a class instance, so this would have nothing to reference. Static methods belong to the class as a whole, rather than to an instance. Constructors use this to refer to another constructor in the same class with a different parameter list.

Java constructor method follows following pattern,

```
public class Test {

    private String s;
    private int i;

    public Test(String s, int i) {

        this.s = s;
        this.i = i;
    }

    public Test() {

        this.s = "Test";
        this.i = 20;
    }
}
```

As you can see above, just like any other method you can overload the constructor. You can call the first constructor and create a object of Test and assign s and i as you desire. Or you can call the second constructor and assign the default values. Look at the example below.

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test t1 = new Test("Hi", 2); //t1.s is now "hi" and t1.i is 2
        Test t2 = new Test(); //t1.s is now "hello" and t1.i is 20
    }
}
```